# E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate on Debian

Tags: debian

I have been trying to install Java 8 on my Debian V-server, but I can't get past the download bc of the error in the Title.

I use the command `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

Answer (score 0):

Well, this solved my Issue:

https://pkgs.org/download/oracle-java8-installer

Just followed the instructions and that's it. Sadly, my Server still won't start, dunno if that's an issue that I can post here